# Botão Command não funciona dentro da ListView Xamarin Forms MVVM

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin-forms, mvvm

Estou tentando criar um botão com o evento `Command` dentro de uma ListView em `MVVM`, porém não está caindo no evento na `ViewModel`.

Como faço para que esse botão `Command` acesse seu método na `ViewModel` ?

E também, como faço para pegar o valor da `Label` "lblCEP" nesse evento `Command` para poder passar para outra view ?

Meu código:

/// **XAML**

```
<ListView x:Name="lvEnderecos" RowHeight="205">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <Label x:Name="lblCEP" Font="14" TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding CliEndCep, StringFormat='CEP: {0}'}"></Label>
              <Grid x:Name="GridControl3" RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackLayout x:Name="stkManipularEndereco" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Padding="5, 0, 0, 0" HeightRequest="25" WidthRequest="25">
                  <Button x:Name="btnEditarEndereco" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Image="editar2.png" HeightRequest="25" WidthRequest="25" Command="{Binding EditarEnderecoCommand}" />
                </StackLayout>
              </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
```

/// **ViewModel**

```
public ICommand EditarEnderecoCommand { get; protected set; }

        this.EditarEnderecoCommand = new Command(async () =>
        {
           try
           {
                await page.DisplayAlert("Alerta", "Você clicou aqui :)", "OK");
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
                throw ex;
           }
       });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na verdade, se a configuração `MVVM` estiver correto, está funcionando sim.

Porém no comportamento é disparado não na `vm` e sim na classe que está sendo listada.

Ex: Se sua `listview`está sendo preenchida por `List<Endereco>` o botão vai 'disparar' a ação dentro da classe `Endereco`

Conheço duas formas de resolver isso, a primeira o `ICommand` dentro da sua classe.

A segunda é utilizar um este componente https://www.nuget.org/packages/Corcav.Behaviors/

Blogue com exemplo: http://codeworks.it/blog/?p=216

```
<Button Text="{Binding NickName}">
 <b:Interaction.Behaviors>
   <b:BehaviorCollection>
      <b:EventToCommand CommandNameContext="{b:RelativeContext MainPage}"
       EventName="Clicked"
         CommandName="NickSelectedCommand"
         CommandParameter="{Binding NickName}" />
    </b:BehaviorCollection>
  </b:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Button>
```

A propriedade `{b:RelativeContext MainPage}` informa que a `vm` definida para esta `view (MainPage)` será o 'BindingContext'. Dessa forma, o comando do botão será disparado na `vm MainPageViewModel`.

É importante definir o nome da `view` `x:Name="MainPage">` para que tudo funcione corretamente.

Para pegar o valor do cep e passar como parâmetro utilize a propriedade `CommandParameter`

Utilizo uma abordagem diferente da sua, mas pelo que pesquiseis (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/) acredito que o código para pegar o parâmetro seria assim:

```
this.EditarEnderecoCommand = new Command<string>((parametro) =>
                {
                });
```

Comment: eu fiz a chamada do botão no code behind e funcionou. Vou fazer por lá mesmo, porém eu coloco o binding do cep no CommandParameter do botão, mas como faço pra pegar esse valor lá no code behind ?

Comment: @AndreeH Adicionei na resposta

Answer (score 0):

Achei outra forma de fazer que no meu caso funcionou, porém só se for para fazer funcionar o evento `Command` sem usar o `CommandParameter`.

Adicionei `BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference lvEnderecos}, Path=BindingContext}"`referenciando o nome da minha ListView.

Então ficou assim:

```
 <Button x:Name="btnEditarEndereco" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Image="editar2.png" HeightRequest="25" WidthRequest="25" BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference lvEnderecos}, Path=BindingContext}" Command="{Binding EditarEnderecoCommand}"/>
```

Se for para funcionar os dois, tanto o `Command` como o `CommandParameter`, eu achei a solução e respondi nessa minha outra pergunta: [Passar e pegar o CommandParameter de um botão Xamarin Forms](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173755/passar-e-pegar-o-commandparameter-de-um-bot%C3%A3o-xamarin-forms/174074#174074)