# Passar e pegar o CommandParameter de um botão Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, button, xamarin-forms

Como passar um valor que está em um `Binding` pelo `CommandParameter` de um botão que está dentro de uma `ListView` para a `ViewModel` ?

O botão está acessando o `Command` certinho, porém não sei se é assim que passa o `CommandParameter` e nem como pegar o valor dele na `ViewModel`.

Como posso fazer isso ?

Meu código:

\\ **XAML**

```
<ListView x:Name="lvEnderecos" RowHeight="205">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <Label x:Name="lblCEP" Font="14" TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding CliEndCep, StringFormat='CEP: {0}'}"></Label>
              <Grid x:Name="GridControl3" RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackLayout x:Name="stkManipularEndereco" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Padding="5, 0, 0, 0" HeightRequest="25" WidthRequest="25">
                  <Button x:Name="btnEditarEndereco" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Image="editar2.png" HeightRequest="25" WidthRequest="25" BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference lvEnderecos}, Path=BindingContext}" Command="{Binding EditarEnderecoCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding CliEndCep}" />
                </StackLayout>
              </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
```

\\ **ViewModel**

```
    this.EditarEnderecoCommand = new Command(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
             page.DisplayAlert("Alerta", "Você clicou aqui :)", "OK");
        }                
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             throw ex;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Recentemente fiz uma postagem sobre a implementação do command, eu utilizo Command<> sendo o argumento generico o que vai ser recebido. Da uma olhada aqui, espero que te ajude. https://guiadosprogramadores.wordpress.com/2016/12/21/mvvm-e-seus-commands/

Comment: Creio que seja possível fazer como o @FilipeSantiago mostrou, porém, usando a classe do Binding por si mesma, você só teria que tratar de pegar o valor à partir do Binding, com um `Command<System.Windows.Data.Binding>` :D
Não posso fazer um exemplo no momento :(

Comment: No Xamarin nem precisa implementar o Command<>, ele já tem nativo da biblioteca. Facilita ainda mais, só adicionar os parametro de tipo.

Comment: Não foi resolvido aqui:http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173501/bot%C3%A3o-command-n%C3%A3o-funciona-dentro-da-listview-xamarin-forms-mvvm/173634#173634 ?

Comment: Não @rubStackOverflow, somente a questão do evento Command. Falta essa parte de passar e pegar o valor do CommandParameter.

Answer (score 3):

Achei a solução para o meu problema, Eu adicionei o nome pro `ContentPage` que no caso contem a minha `ListView` e os demais componentes.

Assim:

```
x:Name="MeusEnderecosView"
```

No meu `Command` eu adicionei o `BindingContext` referenciando o nome dessa `ContentPage`.

Dessa forma:

```
Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.ExcluirEnderecoCommand, Source={x:Reference MeusEnderecosView}}"
```

E o `CommandParameter` ficou assim:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
```

E na `ViewModel`, para pegar o valor de algum `Binding` da View é só fazer dessa forma:

```
this.ExcluirEnderecoCommand = new Command<Endereco>(async (model) => 
{
     Endereco objEnd = new Endereco();
     objEnd.EndCep = model.EndCep;
     objEnd.EndCodigo = model.EndCodigo;
});
```